# Cordova/PhoneGap 4 Notification not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently working on a PhoneGap/Cordova project. I am using Cordova v4. My problem is that the notification dialogs are not working. I already added the plugin via CLI based on its documentation [here](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.dialogs).

And on my index.js file, under the `onDeviceReady` function, I added this code:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

And here's my `alertDismissed` function:

```
function alertDismissed(){
    console.log('alert dismissed');
}
```

Do you have any idea what's the problem? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: post your `alertDismissed` function

Comment: Its just a callback function sir @chip. I'll edit my post and show you a sample `alertDismissed` function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work. I just created a new project and install all the  plugins that I needed including this one and copy all my assets to the newly created project. And voila! it works!